# Getting the first day of each week in javascript / moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Is there a way to get all the dates in the weeks or just the first day of each week and the last day of each week?

For example:

date = 2020-04-15

Then a code will get the date and take all the starting day of the week and the end day.
The expected output is:

Week 1: 2020-04-06 to 2020-04-12

Week 2: 2020-04-13 to 2020-04-19

Week 3: 2020-04-20 to 2020-04-26

Week 4: 2020-04-27 to 2020-05-03

Comment: Nope. There is  no direct way. You can though use loops for it

Comment: based on a date, you want all the start and end dates of a week for that month?

Answer (score 0):

Get the first day of the current week (Sunday):

```
moment().subtract(moment().weekday(), 'days');
```

Get the last day of the current week (Satursday):

```
moment().add(6 - moment().weekday(), 'days');
```

Comment: Note that weekday depends on the current locale. So depending on the needs, it might be better to use isoWeekday instead.

Comment: But this only outputs 1. I need it to be just like in the expected output.